# Create a loop that ends once enemy is dead

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I use Javascript OOP to make a loop that goes until player has defeated the enemy?

```
var character = {};
character.health = 5;
character.damage = 1;

var npc = {};
npc.health = 5;

do {
    npc.health = npc.health -= character.damage;
    document.write(npc.health + "<br>");
}

while (npc.health != 0);
    if (npc.health == 0) {
        document.write("Player wins.");
    }
```

This works when Character damage is set to 1 but once it's above 1 it loops forever and the browser crashes? I'm confused.  Also how do I get it to display 0 rather than going into the negative digits like -1 etc?

Comment: I think that you want to change `npc.health = npc.health -= character.damage;` to `npc.health -= character.damage;`

Comment: You might also want to change the condition for npc.health to go below zero to avoid infinite looping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First lets adjust the loop to work with the case where the "win" may be because the health has become negative,

```
do {
    npc.health -= character.damage;
    document.write(npc.health + "<br>");
} while (npc.health > 0);

if (npc.health <= 0) {
    document.write("Player wins.");
}
```

Now, as you don't want to display negatives, so I'd suggest moving the `if` inside the loop and `break`ing to leave it instead of using a condition. This gives you more control over where you depart the loop and what exactly happens.

```
while (true) {
    npc.health -= character.damage;
    if (npc.health <= 0) { // player won
        // fix the health value to what you want
        npc.health = 0;
        // create output as desired
        document.write(npc.health + "<br>");
        document.write("Player wins.");
        // leave the loop
        break;
    }
    document.write(npc.health + "<br>");
}
```

Before entering this loop you may also wish to check that `character.damage` is positive,

```
if (character.damage > 0) while (true) // etc..
```

---

Finally, this pattern can easily be extended for the *NPC* attacking the *Player* too

```
if (character.damage > 0 || npc.damage > 0) // the loop will ultimately end
    while (true) {
        // chatacter attacks NPC
        npc.health -= character.damage;
        if (npc.health <= 0) { // player won
            // fix the health value to what you want
            npc.health = 0;
            // create output as desired
            document.write('Them: ' + npc.health + "<br>");
            document.write("Player wins.");
            // leave the loop
            break;
        }
        document.write('Them: ' + npc.health + "<br>");
        // NPC attacks character
        character.health -= npc.damage;
        if (character.health <= 0) { // npc won
            // fix the health value to what you want
            character.health = 0;
            // create output as desired
            document.write('You: ' + character.health + "<br>");
            document.write("NPC wins.");
            // leave the loop
            break;
        }
        document.write('You: ' + character.health + "<br>");
    }
```

If you wish to extend this further you may find the loop becoming overly complicated. You have the choice of moving sections of it into functions so it is clearer to read.

Comment: Thank you for this super clear explanation.  Also thanks to everyone else since their answers also gave similar insight!

Answer (score 5):

If your `character.damage` is 2, think about the iterations of your loop.

After the first iteration, `npc.health` will be 3.

After the second iteration, `npc.health` will be 1.

After the third iteration, `npc.health` will be -1.

Since your `while` condition is `npc.health != 0`, your loop will continue forever, because `npc.health` will never be 0, it will just continue to get more and more negative.

Changing your `while` condition to `npc.health > 0` should fix your problem.

To not show negative health for the `npc`, after you subtract `character.damage`, just add an `if` statement, before you use `document.write()` to display the `npc.health`.

```
if (npc.health < 0) {
    npc.health = 0;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I thought you were placing this condition elsewhere, deleting my comment

Comment: Thank you for the very detailed help!

Answer (score 0):

Here as per me, there is some problem with the logic in your program. So I put changed program here and try your luck. I haven't tested this code, but I think it will work.

```
var character = {};
character.health = 5;
character.damage = 1;

var npc = {};
npc.health = 5;

do {
    npc.health -= character.damage;
    if(npc.health>0)document.write(npc.health + "<br>");
    else break;
}while (npc.health > 0);

if (npc.health <= 0) {
    document.write("Player wins.");
}
```

Here if you put `character.damage` more than once, then also your loop will be terminated.

Comment: This doesn't address not displaying negative numbers, doesn't offer any explanation, and doesn't really add any more value than the answer that was posted more than 10 minutes before yours. If `npc.health` is not divisible by `character.damage`, this would still display a negative number before breaking the loop.

Comment: so  changed my code and here if health goes negative, then the loop will be braked and the negative number will not be printed.